# ST_ClosestPoint in 2D but retaining Z value

Tags: postgis

I have a query in PostGIS where I have a two geometries, a MultiLineStringZ and a Point.

I want to find the 3D point on the MultiLineStringZ closest to the Point by it's flat 2D plane distance, so essentially ST_ClosestPoint(myMultiLineStringZ, myPoint). However I need to retain the Z value on the returned point. ST_ClosestPoint drops the Z, and ST_3DClosestPoint does a 3D distance calculation.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use st_closestpoint.
Then from the result make a vertical line that passes the multilinestring.
Finally use st_3dclosestpoint between the vertical line and the multiline.

Theoretically you could use st_3dintersects instead but that will cause you problems from precision issues.

Comment: Works a charm! Thanks.

The dirty hack that I also tried was to scale myMultiLineStringZ in the Z axis so as to make the 3D component practically irrelevant than scale back to the original Z value. Your approach is much cleaner though.

Comment: PS. here is the SQL I used,
    ST_3DClosestPoint(
        ST_MakeLine(
            ST_Force3DZ(
                ST_ClosestPoint(myMultiLineStringZ, myPoint)
            ),
            ST_Translate(
                ST_Force3DZ(
                    ST_ClosestPoint(myMultiLineStringZ, myPoint
                )
             ), 0, 0, 100000)
        ),
        myMultiLineStringZ
    )